# Why do I need to wrap in brackets a state setter function in useEffect's dependencies within a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a scenario like the one below:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { GlobalContext } from "context/GlobalState";

const useMyCustomHook = () => {
  const { myGlobalContext } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const [myState, setMyState] = useState<MyStateType | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {

    console.log("This code is never triggered.");

  }, [myGlobalContext, setMyState]);

  return myState;
};
```

The code within the useEffect in the custom hook never gets triggered when it should.

However, when I modify the code to be either of the two options, it works.

```
//...
  }, [myGlobalContext, [setMyState]]);
//..
```

```
//...
  }, [myGlobalContext]);
//..
```

That is, it seems that either removing the setter function, or wrapping it within brackets, makes the code works.

Is there something I am missing? I wasn't aware of any need to wrap any dependency within nested brackets in React.

Comment: Very strange.  The `setMyState` function will always be the same, so it shouldn’t make a difference whether or not you include it in the dependencies.  It should call the effect whenever any of the dependencies change so it should call it when the `myGlobalContext` changes.  That is, I would expect `[myGlobalContext, setMyState]);` and `[myGlobalContext]);` to behave the same and I cannot explain why they don’t.

Comment: Wrapping it in brackets would mean that the effect depends on that array, which you created inline, so that version would run the effect on every re-render, I would think.

Comment: Maybe you can gain some insight by playing around the Profiler section of dev tools.  Do some recordings and examine the “why this component re-rendered” part.